# Service throws "The underlying provider failed on Open" error randomly

Tags: sql, entity-framework, service, database-connection, connection-string

I have a singular issue with my Entity Framework code. I have a service; very night, it makes some update operations on my database. Sometimes, it seems almost randomly, it return the error:

> The underlying provider failed on Open

Reading around, the problem seems to be the connection string, but all the hints I read are already set in my connection string. My connection string is:

```
metadata=res://*/Entities.csdl|res://*/Entities.ssdl|res://*/VEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
 connection string="Data Source=192.168.1.100\INSTANCE;
 Initial Catalog=dbName;
 Persist Security Info=True;
 User ID=user;
 Password=pwd;
 MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Do you have some ideas? It works almost all the time, but sometimes it returns this error. After the error, there is the same message for the following minutes and, after a while, it works well again.

Ask me for further details, if I can, I'll give them to you.

UPDATE:

Here the stacktrace

```
System.Data.EntityException: Errore del provider sottostante in Open. —-> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Si è verificato un errore di rete o specifico dell'istanza mentre si cercava di stabilire una connessione con SQL Server. Il server non è stato trovato o non è accessibile. Verificare che il nome dell'istanza sia corretto e che SQL Server sia configurato in modo da consentire connessioni remote. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Errore nell'individuazione del server/dell'istanza specificata)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   in System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   —- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna —-
   in System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   in System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   in System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   in System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   in xxx.yyy.kkk(String[] array, String storeid, Int32& idimp, DateTime& datelast)
```

Comment: please add total stack trace.also check this..https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2012/08/09/error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open-in-entity-framework-application/

Comment: Have you added in your classpath the connection driver?

Comment: @TheGameiswar stacktrace inserted. Alerady read the link, nothing useful for me

Comment: @JoeTaras what do you mean? I can't get what you're talking about

Comment: @PieroAlberto: Sorry, I've read better the error. When you try to connect from your client with Sql Server (for example by Management Studio) you get the connection? Maybe Sql Server doesn't accept remote connection?

Comment: @JoeTaras Yes, Management Studio works. And I think I'm also able to create remote connection, since my software works for a while, then... this error! But before and after it, it works normally